# Ionic 1 push notification

Tags: ionic-framework

Does someone have experience with ionic 1 push notifications?  Is there any alternative to cloud solution that they suggest? And can someone show example of  implementatio? And please have on mind that I'm completly new in ionic

Comment: Hi. You can refer to this [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/). The explanation  is easy to understand. Let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 4):

I use this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push to handle push notification.

```
var pushOptions = {
    android: {
        senderID: "1234567890",
        icon: "push_icon",
        iconColor: "#FFF"
    },
    ios: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    }
};

var push = PushNotification.init(pushOptions);

push.on('registration', function () {});

push.on('notification', function () {});
```

Comment: can you please tell what is sender Id ?

Comment: Sure! Basically, the sender ID is your project's unique identifier in FCM/GCM (Firebase Cloud Message or Google Cloud Message, this second is the older version of FCM). 

The sender ID is used to help the Cloud Message to get the authorization from your application to send the notification.

Comment: Thanks for the Info :)

Answer (score 1):

After test several push servicies (ionic push service, parse, pushwoosh and one signal) we choose [one signal](https://onesignal.com/) as push notification provider. Right now we use it in 30+ production applications in our company. In 10 minutes or less you can set up an app for first push notification use in android or iOS (platforms we are working right now)

The platform has an easy [set up guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup).
The only code in app for basic setup is:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

   // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("YOUR_APPID")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();

  // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your app if you have the user's email.
  // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail);
})
```

Just modify "YOUR_APPID" by yours and thats all.
Follow de docs above for make it works in your desired platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It's free, easy to use and multi-platform Push Notification framework.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.