# Popup notification to be displayed in mobile

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1 framework for  mobile apps. I want my push notifications to be displayed as popups like truecaller even app is remains closed . What are the plugins that may get used?

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it's helpful, Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 1 push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591617/ionic-1-push-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Check out `OneSignal`. It's 100% free and developer-friendly to use on multi-platforms.

OneSignal provides a simple interface to push notifications and email, letting content creators focus on quality user engagement instead of complex implementation

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup

Comment: I want to notify for once in a day , but instead onesignal is sending for every hour.

Comment: You can call OneSignal API using cron jobs

Comment: I want to display notifications similar to truecaller popup window , even application remains closed.

Comment: You can use heads up notifications like data notifications in Firebase